# Finding position of utf8 substring in string in python

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am trying to find a utf-8 substring in a string.

Here is my code:

```
str = u'haha i am going home'
substr1 = u'haha'
substr2 = u'ha'
```

if i run

```
str.find(substr1) #returns 0 
str.find(substr2) #returns 0
```

I would like

`str.find(substr2) to return -1` instead as there i want to match by word instead.

Comment: You don't have UTF-8 strings. You have Unicode strings; the two concepts are related but very much not the same thing. One is encoded bytes, the other is text.

Comment: Write your own function.

Comment: `str` is a Python type, be sure to use another variable name.

Comment: FWIW, a simple way to do this without regex is to append a space to both your target string and your search strings. OTOH, unlike the regex approach, that doesn't handle punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex

```
import re

str = u'haha i am going home'
substr1 = u'haha'
substr2 = u'ha'

match = re.search(r'\b%s\b' % substr1 ,str)

if match:
    print "found substring 1"

match = re.search(r'\b%s\b' % substr2 ,str)

if match:
    print "found substring 2"
```